# What is paleo Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, clone, redirection

Through googling (the thing that one should do before asking a question) I found a site
`paleo.stackexchange.com`, which redirects to `paleohacks.com`. It does not seem to have any relation to the Stackexchange network, and it looks like it belongs to Answerhub (link present in the footer).

What is this page? If it does not belong to Stackexchange, why does it forward to this page?

Comment: this is likely the place for neanderthal programmers